# Java 8: How to create a ZonedDateTime from an Epoch value?

Tags: java, java-8, epoch, zoneddatetime

Java 8's `LocalDateTime` has an `ofEpochSecond` method. Unfortunately, there is no such method in the `ZonedDateTime`. Now, I have an Epoch value and an explicit `ZoneId` given. How do I get a `ZonedDateTime` out of these?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the `Instant` class, which can represent a moment given the epoch time. If you have epoch seconds, you might create something via something like

```
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochSecond(t);
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, zoneId);
```

Comment: `ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneOffset.UTC)` for UTC

Comment: `Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(t); ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York"); ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);` for a specific ZoneId.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple way (different from that of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28808481/10819573)) is to use [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sample Epoch seconds and ZoneId
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1665256187);
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");

        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Alternatively
        zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-10-08T20:09:47+01:00[Europe/London]
2022-10-08T20:09:47+01:00[Europe/London]
```

Learn about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.