# convert milliseconds to java date with offset hours (Z05:00)

Tags: java, cassandra, datetime-format, timezone-offset, milliseconds

How to convert string value in milliseconds to the string of date format as `"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`? (inlcuding offset with Z)

Comment: `(Z05:00), Z07:00` - Which is it?

Comment: [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to create a ZonedDateTime from an Epoch value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808305/java-8-how-to-create-a-zoneddatetime-from-an-epoch-value)

Comment: Similar q to [java convert milliseconds to time format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/java-convert-milliseconds-to-time-format).

Comment: It’s a peculiar format, are you sure? You may want to explain why you need precisely this format. Would `Z07:00` refer to offset +07:00 from UTC (as in Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Saigon and many other time zones)? If so, would there also be a way to represent a negative offset? Should the offset always be 07:00, or should , for example, the JVM’s time zone setting be used?

Comment: @Ole.Offset can be anythiing. I might change the offset to UTC (America/NY).So, I need to achieve the reuired format, so other apis in golang can parse it without errors. e.g., an issue that I am facing now is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303326/how-to-parse-non-standard-time-format-from-json-in-golang.

Comment: I don’t know any Golang. However from [Formatting date and time in Golang](https://medium.com/@Martynas/formatting-date-and-time-in-golang-5816112bf098) i seem to gather that `Z07:00` is a *placeholder*, and that the offset in the formatted string should be like for example `+03:00`. I think you should check.

Comment: I suggest learning about the ISO 8601 standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: Your string is a placeholder string

I believe that `"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"` is Golang’s way to specify a date-time format. An ISO 8601 format to be more precise. The actual formatted string would be like for example `2018-09-19T00:26:42-05:00`. So use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")` or just `DatetimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` (and no substitutions after the formatter has formatted the string).

### Original answer

This goes in two steps:

1. Convert your milliseconds string (I assume since the epoch of 1970-01-01) to an `Instant`.
2. Convert the `Instant` to the desired time zone and format it.

The challenge is with the second step. Offsets have signs, positive or negative, and the standard formatting options for offsets include either `-` or `+` (except that offset zero is sometimes written as just `Z` without sign). Here’s my go at the whole thing:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Denver");
    DateTimeFormatter firstShotFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'xxx");

    String milliseconds = "1136239445000";

    Instant pointInTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.parseLong(milliseconds));
    String firstShot = pointInTime.atZone(zone).format(firstShotFormatter);
    // Offset should be negative
    if (firstShot.contains("Z-")) {
        // Remove minus sign from formatted offset
        String result = firstShot.replace("Z-", "Z");
        System.out.println("Formatted string: " + result);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Don’t know how to format a positive offset from UTC");
    }
```

The output from this snippet is:

> Formatted string: 2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00

I have tentatively guessed that your offset of `Z07:00` referred to North American Mountain Time, which is at offset -07:00 in January. Please check. I didn’t know how to handle a positive offset, so my code checks that it doesn’t occur.

I find the format you asked for peculiar. It ressembles ISO 8601 with its characteristic `T` between the date and the time part. But to the best of my knowledge ISO 8601 would have the offset as *either* `Z` (for zero) *or* signed, for example `-07:00`,  never a mixture of those. You may want to check if you can persuade the receiver of your formatted string to accept a straight ISO 8601 string instead. I’d find this much cleaner and in the end easier to understand for all parties.

### Links

- [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Formatting date and time in Golang](https://medium.com/@Martynas/formatting-date-and-time-in-golang-5816112bf098)

Comment: Let me try and get back.